# How to select all row and give boolean mark the row with max value of a column (with multiple marking)? (Java Native Query, Psql)

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, greatest-n-per-group, hibernate-native-query

Currently I am working on giving a label to my data. I will give the label to data that marked as highest on the resulting query. the problem is the label is not only for 1 case but multiple, and also I need pagination for the query using Pageable.

*Note: I need it by query because I think it's not feasible to do in Java because 1. the API might have big number of hit, 2. the logic of pagination containing page_number and page_size and sorting query.

---

Example of data

| id | name | power | heigh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | ace | 1000 | 170 |
| uuid2 | luffy | 990 | 168 |
| uuid3 | zorro | 980 | 167 |
| uuid4 | sanji | 970 | 180 |

---

Mocked result that I wanted when I queried is like this

| id | name | power | is_highest_power | heigh | is_highest_heigh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| uuid1 | ace | 1000 | true | 170 | false |
| uuid2 | luffy | 990 | false | 168 | false |
| uuid3 | zorro | 980 | false | 167 | false |
| uuid4 | sanji | 970 | false | 180 | true |

---

Currently, working on it with Postgresql db with java JPARepository interface.
I need to build the native query with pagination in it and also a filter for the result.

```
@Query(
      nativeQuery = true,
      countQuery = "SELECT count(1) "
          + " FROM user u "
          + " WHERE (:startPower IS NULL OR u.power >= :startPower) AND "
          + " (:startHeigh IS NULL OR u.heigh >= :startHeigh)",
      value = "SELECT u.id, u.name, u.power, u.is_highest_power (??), u.heigh, "
          + " u.is_highest_heigh (??)"
          + " FROM user u "
          + " WHERE (:startPower IS NULL OR u.power >= :startPower) AND "
          + " (:startHeigh IS NULL OR u.heigh >= :startHeigh)"
  )
  Page<SearchUser> searchUser(
      Pageable pageable,
      BigDecimal startPower,
      BigDecimal startHeigh
  );


public interface SearchUser {

  @Value("#{target.id}")
  String getId();

  @Value("#{target.name}")
  String getName();

  @Value("#{target.power}")
  BigDecimal getPower();

  @Value("#{target.is_highest_power}")
  Boolean getIsHighestPower();

  @Value("#{target.heigh}")
  BigDecimal getHeigh();

  @Value("#{target.is_highest_heigh}")
  Boolean getIsHighestHeigh();
```

I have found how to query to get the highest power or heigh (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)) but can not found how to mark a row as the highest and query it as the result column too.

How to achieve this in nativeQuery string?

Comment: How much data do you have? If it's not a ton, I would query the DB for all the data. I would then use code to find the highest power and the highest high. I am not sure how pagination works with `Spring`, so I am not going to comment on that.

Comment: The data might be hunderds, like there is no delete operation on the data, but there is date expiration, so data will be exclude by using the date < now().

Comment: Sounds like a small memory amount. It should be doable.

Comment: I think no. The problem is 1. the API might have big number of hit, 2. the logic of pagination containing page_number and page_size and sorting query. I will update the question why is it not doable by using Java to loop and do the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if using `CASE WHEN` helps.

```
SELECT id, name, power, 
CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(power) FROM user) = power THEN true ELSE false END AS is_highest_power,
heigh,
CASE WHEN (SELECT MAX(heigh) FROM user) = heigh THEN true ELSE false END AS is_highest_heigh
FROM user
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: can I ask is there any analysis on performance for large data like hundreds rows or thousands row

Comment: You will have to run the query to see how long it takes. I am not sure.

Comment: cool, this answer what I wanted, and works with the Java JPA native query